# Strange issue with Account and contact fields on case object

Tags: page-layout, security, field-level-security

For some reason the account and contact field on the case object is grayed out, my initial guess was FLS or page layout making the field read only but all have the fields open for my profile, not sure whats making these two fields grayed out still. Can anyone point any reasons

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have any look up filters defined on account or contact?

Comment: unfortunately not, its a open field i have for both account and contact, is there something i am missing

Comment: have added a screenshot of the current account field which is open

Comment: are you logged in with standard Sys admin profile?

Comment: Yes i am a system admin, this is a personal developer instance, not sure what is causing this issue. Any help very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce support recognized the problem and raised this to R&D, after 27 days of analysis between tier 2-3 and R&D they found the problem. It was the platform encryption that i enabled that caused the issued. Once they rerun the job(backend salesforce job for encryption) this issue was resolved. The lookup started working now. FYI for all stuck with similar issue.

[image]